# phyghtmap 2.23 reversing / flipping coordinates

Tags: gdal, phyghtmap

I have downloaded [this zip](http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3/L35.zip) from viewfinderpanoramas, it corresponds with the middle of Romania and contains files like N44E24.hgt, N44E025.hgt, etc. From these I create a `warp-60.tif` GeoTIFF by running:

```
gdal_merge.py -n 32767 -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -o raw.tif *.hgt.tif
gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 60 60 raw.tif warp-60.tif
```

Then I want to create a contours .pbf file but when I run...

```
phyghtmap -o contour --max-nodes-per-tile=0 -s 10 -0 --pbf warp-60.tif
```

... I get `contour_lon44.00_48.00lat24.00_30.00_local-source.osm.pbf` which has the latitude and longitude clearly flipped in the filename. If I import this file, the contours are somewhere in Saudi Arabia not in Romania as they should be.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546) on Github linked from tens of places having coordinate issues and I'm wondering if it's the same problem for me also. And if so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was indeed the one I linked and I was able to fix it by downloading the source, patching `phyghtmap/hgt.py` in 3 places and then installing.

The patched file is [here](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7).

The changes are on lines [131](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7#file-hgt-py-L131), [134 - 136](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7#file-hgt-py-L134-L136), [171](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7#file-hgt-py-L171), [181 - 183](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7#file-hgt-py-L181-L183), [543](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7#file-hgt-py-L543) and [551 - 553](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7#file-hgt-py-L551-L553).

---

Update with detailed steps:

1. Uninstall phyghtmap (on Ubuntu I did `sudo apt remove phyghtmap`). Check that it's removed by trying to run `phyghtmap` - it should error out.
2. [Download the sources](http://katze.tfiu.de/projects/phyghtmap/phyghtmap_2.23.orig.tar.gz) somewhere you prefer and unzip them.
3. In the unzipped directory replace the `phyghtmap/hgt.py` file with the [one provided](https://gist.github.com/janosrusiczki/691407a94aceb059cfdc68e018c646a7).
4. Still in the unzipped directory do `sudo python3 setup.py install` - This should install the patched version.
5. Check if phyghtmap is working again.